# Change the default Java icon

Tags: java, swing, icons, default, executable

I would like to change the default Java icon (the design of the cup). I used the code below in the constructors of JFrames of my system and it worked only when I run the system in Netbeans, but when I generate the executable can not start my program!

```
setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(getClass().getResource("/ICONES/add.png")));
```

Comment: Because the image should be included to the JAR.

Comment: open your JAR file using program like 7zip then put your ICONES folder inside it.

Comment: @fev Or Just use a build system which includes the resources or a suitable IDE...

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I have no doubt on you !

Comment: Also see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306872/seticonimage-only-works-in-eclipse-doesnt-work-when-exported-as-runnable-jar-fi/27307113#27307113), [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224184/sizes-of-frame-icons-used-in-swing) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825481/setting-an-icon-for-my-java-application/19825494#19825494) for a more flexible alernative

Comment: Hello.

If I open my executable with Winrar for example, I can see that the ICONS folder, where my image is already in the executable. And now, what to do?